# dropdownlist is not binded with correct values in ajax success

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have used multiselect dropdown plugin where I need to bind array in ajax success.When array is declared static it is showing correct result but when it is binded dynamic it shows undefined in dropdown items

```
 success: function (Result) {
                         Result = Result.d;
                         var opt1 = [];
                         var optfull =
                                        [{ label: 'Aetna', value: '1' },
                                        { label: 'Anthem Blue Cross', value: '2' },
                                            { label: 'Anthem Blue Cross', value: '2' },
                                            { label: 'Anthem Blue Cross', value: '2' }]


                         //                         opt1 = $.map(data.d, function (item) {
                         //                             return (opt1 += opt1.length == 0 ? "[{ label:'" + item.split('-')[0] + "', value:'" + item.split('-')[1] + "', selected: true}]" : "[{ label:'" + item.split('-')[0] + "', value:'" + item.split('-')[1] + "'},]");
                         //
                         //                        });
                         //                      
                         $('[id$=lstHPlan]').multiselect('dataprovider', opt1);
                         $('[id$=lstHPlan]').multiselect('dataprovider', optfull );
```

Comment: Have you returned it in document.ready?

Comment: It is binding but showing all values undefined in dropdownlist